# Leaving XMPPRoom

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xmppframework

Im developing an app that can log in the user in 2 xmpprooms, but only 2 at the same time, so if he wants to connect to another one I have to disconnect him from the previous and connect to the next one. Whith this code:

This is how I leave the room:

```
[[xmppRoom] leaveRoom]; 
[[xmppRoom] deactivate];
[[xmppRoom] removeDelegate:self];
```

And this is how I join the room:

```
[xmppRoom activate:[self xmppStream]];                
[xmppRoom joinRoom];
```

The funky behaviour is that if the room has more than 10 users it crashes without errors but if I enable NSZombies I see that the pointer is in the method `[XMPPRoom isJoined]`, in this line:

```
dispatch_sync(moduleQueue, ^{
   result = _isJoined;
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide alot of information to work with, but your problem might be fixed by looking into [this article](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#enter-maxusers) that explains max users and how it handles max users. Good documentation by the way, I strongly recommend you check this out. And if you have any future xmpp problems, check this website first.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the number of users, since I can connect more users via Spark.

Comment: It also appears as if the attribute "isJoined" was distroyed, only when it leaves a room with moren than 10 users.

Comment: Hey @subharb, can you guys please help me with this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007090/xmpproomdidleave-delegate-gets-called